# BlackBerry10: How to copy file from device to the pc

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I want copy database and log files of my program to the PC.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Momentics developemnt environmen includes a Target File System Navigator (Windows -> Show View). If it is not on that menu select other an then enter Target in the search box. Using the Target File System Navigator you may browse system and sandbox files, and copy them to the PC.